# Send raw data to printer programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I want to send to my printer data I load from a file so that it can print a barcode (ITF 2/5).

if I use the command prompt and do "print c:\test lpt1", it works like a charm and it prints the expected barcode. However, when I try to do this programmatically, the printer fails to provide said barcode. Readable text works fine, it's (so far) exclusively an issue I have with the barcode printing.

I have the following code in which ( I thought ) I would be sending a printer raw data (not rendered in any way) so that the printer can decide how to decode those bytes I'm sending to it.

```
std::FILE* fd = fopen("c:\\test", "rb");
std::fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
int size = std::ftell(fd);
std::fseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
int beginning = std::ftell(fd);
if(fd == NULL)
{
    std::cerr << "Error opening file\n";
    return;
}
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(size);
std::fread(buffer, 1, size, fd);
std::ofstream output("lpt1", std::ios_base::out);
output << buffer;
```

My only guess (and a blind one, at that) is that I am mistakingly assuming the ofstream is receiving raw data when it's not... and I don't know why or how to solve that.

I am not asking for a 'do my homework for me' answer (Although a very clear and epic answer would be awesome) but at least if you could point me in the right way of why I am not getting the expected result, I would be really grateful. Even some keywords for searching and researching on my own would be great, too. I honestly have no idea of what I am doing wrong.

This is some new code I tried because of a suggestion to use IOStreams, again, I get NOT the desired result when I try to edit the content of input.rdbuf().

```
static void ImprimirArchivo(unsigned char* path)
{
    std::ifstream input((char*)path, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream output("lpt1", std::ios::binary);

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> streamInputIterator (input.rdbuf());

    bool codeBarStarted = false;
    int iterationsCounter = 0;
    while(streamInputIterator!=eos)
    {
        if(*streamInputIterator == 0x14)
        {
            output << '1d';
            output << '6b';
            output << '05';
            output << '30';
            codeBarStarted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            output << *streamInputIterator;
        }

        if(codeBarStarted)
        {
            iterationsCounter++;
            if(iterationsCounter == 10)
            {
                output << 0x00;
                codeBarStarted = false;
                iterationsCounter = 0;
            }
        }

        streamInputIterator++;
    }
```

Please note that when I do
            if(*streamInputIterator == 0x14)
            {
                output << '1d';
                output << '6b';
                output << '05';
                codeBarStarted = true;
            }

If I replace that with
            if(*streamInputIterator == 0x14)
            {
                output << 0x1d;
                output << 0x6b;
                output << 0x05;
                codeBarStarted = true;
            }

the corresponding output is still wrong, but wholly different. When I use 0xXY, what's printed is the decimal number as in: output << 0x1d makes the printer print "29" (text).

Comment: You'd better use ios_base::binary.

Comment: you mean the mode of the ofstream?

Answer (score 1):

A short in the dar: Open both files in binary mode, in particular `std::ofstream`:

```
std::ofstream output("lpt1", std::ios::binary);
```

(there is no need to also specify `std::ios::out` because it is added when opening a `std::ofstream` anyway but you could use `std::ios::out | std::ios_binary` if you want).

Personally, I would use IOStreams for both the input and the output:

```
std::ifstream input("c:\\test", std::ios::binary);
if (input) {
    std::ofstream("lpt1", std::ios::binary) << input.rdbuf();
}
else {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to open 'c:\\test' for reading\n";
}
```

Comment: The IOStreams work. However, I want to be able to edit the content of the streams,such as find and replace certain bytes in it. How could I do this with the streams? I am not working with text, but with raw data.

I want to PARSE the content of the input stream, edit it with arbitrary data (for example: if I find a 0x14, I want to insert 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 instead) and then send it to lpt1.

I tried exporting the content of the rdbuf to an std::vector<unsigned char> and then sending the vector to the printer but this goes back to not printing my codebar.

Comment: If you can do the decide on the fly what needs to be done, you can iterated over the input using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and just print the additional characters when a suitable condition is encountered. Alternatively, you can read the data into a suitable container, e.g., using `std::string s((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input)), std::isteambuf_iterator());` (there are many other approaches).